# Countdown 3rd array element and print sorted even numbers

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I am trying to solve this task I have and I do not seem to know what is the issue with it exactly.
My task requires the following;
1- countdown from a given number by 3
2- only print the even numbers
4- sorted

what I did so far;

```
function cd (num){
  let arrayCount = [];
  let arrayEven = [];
        for(let i = 0; i <= num; i++) {
              arrayCount.push(num-i);
        }
        //return arrayCount;
       for (let j = 0; j <= arrayCount.length; j+=3) {
           if (arrayCount[j] % 2 == 0) {
            arrayEven.push(arrayCount[j]);
           }
       }
       arrayEven.sort(function(a,b){return a - b;});
       return arrayEven;
    
}
console.log(cd(10)); // expected output [4]
console.log(cd(23)); // expected output [2,8,14,20]
console.log(cd(103)); // expected output [4,10,16,22,28,34,40,46,52,58,64,70,76,82,88,94,100]
console.log(cd(15)); //expected output [6,12]
```

My issue is with input 15 and 10 and I am not sure what I am doing work. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: And that is exactly why this task is confusing me! I have tried to sort then filter the evens and the other was around but nothing seem to work with me. I feel like I am misting something here but I am not sure what...

Comment: That is the thing, these are the outputs they are expecting. I hade to make it complicated just cause I was not sure the simplified one would do what they are asking. I will try to play around with it and see. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

So, I figured out what was missing. The thing is that the loop  would always print the first element and THEN apply the conditions you want on the rest of the elemnts, and that is why in input [10] the number 10 was printed. In short, I just needed to let my loop start from i = num-3. Thank you for you comments as they helped me a lot. Although the solution was right there, still I wanted to share the updated part, so here you go:

```
for (let i = num-3; i > 0; i-=3) {
        if (i % 2 == 0) 
            array.push(i);
      } let result = array.sort((a, b) => a - b);
```

Comment: Thank you @PeterJames, your comment helped me a lot. I r-wrote my code again with only one loop in mind trying to skip the first element and see if the results would match the expected outputs is what lead me to the answer.